# c-Segmentation Fault:11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The code is to find all possible combination of numbers present in the array `a` that would add up to a given number `n`. I am getting **segmentation fault** in this piece of code.
The **error is Segmentation Fault:11**. 
Please HELP.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void comb(long long int n,int a[],int k);
long int ct=0;

int main() {
    long long int n;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    int k;
    scanf("%d",&k);
    int a[k];

    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    comb(n,a,k);
    ct=ct*2;
    printf("%ld",ct);
    return 0;
}

void comb(long long int n,int a[],int k)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        ct++;
        return;
    }
    else
        if(n<0)
            return;
        else
        {
            for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
            {
                comb(n-a[j],a,k);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use a debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: yes @EdHeal it does compile.It gave correct output for a few cases but then i got this seg fault.

Comment: Oo look, a wild global variable! You would want to get rid of that too.
As for the original matter, then please tell us in which cases (input combinations) your program fails.

Comment: 40217980
9
13 12 4 9 3 8 2 7 1

Comment: @E_net4 the above input gives set fault

Comment: By _combination_, do you mean k-combination with unlimited repetition?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `scanf` is not **safe**. Use `fgets` and add some **error checking**.

For example if user types a letter on `scanf("%lld", &n);` your program crashes with seg fault.

Comment: this coding problem does not have those sort of test cases.So i don't think that scanf would be an issue.

Comment: If you posted the test cases when posting your question I would have known.

Comment: My fault.The code doesn't seem to work for the following test case

Comment: 40217980
9
13 12 4 9 3 8 2 7 1

Comment: What does the program need to do?

Comment: This is incorrect.scanf will not cause seg fault when letter typed in

Comment: the code finds all possible combination in a that could add up to n.For e.g. n=19 k=2 a->4,5 output->5,5,5,4  5,5,4,5  5,4,5,5  4,5,5,5.Thus output is 4.Here in my code i am just giving twice of this output.